# Cannot get querySelector to work with child nodes

Tags: dart

In the first web page and dart code I've ever written `querySelector` works as I expected.  I've just created, in the same project, a library with a class that displays a second web page (which will be a kind of menu) when the first script creates an instance of that class and initializes it.

The page displays but `querySelector` returns `null` for the child `<div id="text-box"> </div>` but not for its parent, the first element `<div id="main-box">` after `<body>`.  I've used Google to search and looked at APIs and found references to `ShadowRoot` but have not been able to use that.  I've tried chaining `querySelector` but no joy.

How do I access elements within elements?

HTML (simplified)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tools Menu</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" media="screen" href='toolsmenu.css'>
  </head>

  <body>   
    <div id="main-box">      
      <div id="text-box"> </div>
    </div>

    <script type='application/dart' src="ToolsMenu.dart"></script>
    <!-- for this next line to work, your pubspec.yaml file must have a dependency on 'browser' -->
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

dart script for debugging

```
library ToolsMenu;

import 'dart:html';

class ToolsMenu {
  WindowBase windowBase;
  DivElement mainbox;
  DivElement comments = null;

  void initialize() {
    windowBase = window.open("toolsmenu.html", "_newtab");

    //comments = querySelector('#main-box'); // not null
   comments = querySelector('#text-box');    // FAILS
   // debug
   if(comments == null) {   // always null
     windowBase.close();
     return;
    }
   comments.text = 'It Worked!!'; // never reached.          

  }        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`querySelector` only searches the document in the current window. Another window is another Dart application. You need to load a Dart script there and then those two applications can communicate using `postMessage` and `onMessage.listen`. There are a few related questions here on SO how to do it.

Comment: That explains why querySelector finds '#main-box': it's in both html files!!  I have not been able to figure out how, when the user clicks/taps on the tools button on the first script what dart code in the button handler to use to load the 2nd page html page (above). Both html files and dart scripts are in the same base folder.  I do not use port 80 for the dart server.

Comment: Is the Window class the way to go?

Comment: I played around a bit with opening a window and passing message while writing a test for the media-query component in https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/tree/master/test (4 files). It is basically prevened by Dart, you have to work around with dart-js-interop AFAIR.

Comment: I have the new files, toolsmenu.dart, toolsmenu.html, & toolsmenu.css, in the same project as the primary dart script and files.  I can display the page but toolsmenu.dart is not compiled when I build.  Does the new page need to be in its own new project? If not what needs to be done for it to compile?   Perhaps I should start a new post.

Comment: Do you have a Dart script tag in `toolsmenu.html` that points to `toolsmenu.dart`?

Comment: Yes, just like the html above except the case is now lower case: "toolsmenu.dart".  toolsmenu.dart.js is not created and the output from "Tools->Pub Build - Debug" has no mention of "toolsmenu".

Comment: Does your `toolsmenu.dart` contain a `main()`?

Comment: I had an error with main.  It displays and works correctly.  Thanks for your patient help!